# Options for each item of listview Android

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-listview, google-now

I want to create options for each `ListView` item like Google Now Android app.

I Have created a custom `ListView` and each item in the `ListView` will have a overflow image as in Google Now app's UI Card.

Now when I click on that overflow image, I want a dropdown showing the list of operations I can perform on the corresponding item in the ListView.

Can anybody has the solution or alternate to this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is library called `CardUI` that you can use to accomplish your task!

To read more about `CardUI` library go to [CardUI on androidviews.com](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/)

And to download this library go to [This](https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android) link and click on `Zip` button.
That will download the library as a .rar file

Comment: I have seen 'CardUI' library. But I dont want Card in my listview, I just want the operations for each 'ListView' item as shown in Google Now App.